# cant load td innerHTML or buttons on document onLoad returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get the `innetHTML` of a `td`. I have a value inside and I need to get it but I'm getting trouble with page load.

This happens because when the pages load the `td` is null and don't wait for it being fulfilled with a group of permissions.

So I need to get a way of wait for the page to laod everything, including the `td` value of my table. Then when I click in a button to edit that row I can get the `td` value to pass inside the button and perform update actions in the permission group.

So I  tried to use `document.state===ready`, `$state.$on(load)`, add a event listener to `DOMContentLoaded` and nothing worked. It cant go into that part of the code. I don't know why. Now I have:

```
app.controller('OrganizationsPermissionsSettingsController',['$rootScope', '$scope', '$modal', 'HelperService', 'AuthService', '$state', '$http', function ($rootScope, $scope, $modal, HelperService, AuthService, $state, $http) {
        var controllerScope = $scope;


        controllerScope.organizationGroups = [];

        $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups').success(function (data) {
            controllerScope.organizationGroups = data;
        });

        controllerScope.openOrganizationPermissionsSettings = function (organizationId) {
            $state.go('app.organizationPermissionsSettings');
        };

        $rootScope.groupId="";

        var groupName = "";
        var btnGraphs = "";
        var btnViews = "";

        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            alert("loaded");
            groupName = document.getElementById("permissionGroupName");
            console.log("groupName* * * ",$rootScope.groupId);
        });

        $scope.navigateToGraphs = function() {      
            btnGraphs.addEventListener("click", function() { 
                if(groupName.innerHTML!=null){
                    console.log("groupName ",groupName);
                    $http.get('/api/organization_permissions_groups/getId'+groupName).success(function (data) {
                        if(data!=undefined && data != null){
                            $rootScope.groupId=data;
                            console.log("controllerScope.id ",$rootScope.groupId);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            console.log("controllerScope.id graphs",$rootScope.groupId);
            $state.go('app.organizationGraphs');    
        }


    }]);
```

In my view my td has `<td id="permissionGroupName">{{organizationGroup.group_name}}</td>` which retrieves my permission group name.

Comment: try to wrap that inside `$timeout`

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. It looks like you're ignoring a lot of how to do it the angular way. Can you please just ask what you're trying to achieve

Comment: My td will retrieve for example "Administrator" and then I will use that to manipulate his permissions... but for that I need the td value to send the request with the permission group name understand?

Comment: can you post the HTML too? where the user clicks to update

Comment: Here's my plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/jgYBhPuHB3h02VqrAupc?p=catalogue .. I have my main controller organizationController with  a button of permisisons config which triggers permission controller and inside of it I have 2 tabs with each one have a table with 3 rows and each row have a group name.

Comment: Did you have nay ideia to resolve this @SibiRaj ?

Comment: please post a working plunker. literally, I cannot understand anything. If the button is inside a ng-repeat.you could get the data of the row. @AndréBastos

Answer (score -1):

you can use 
     $scope.$apply(function () {})
being able to use

setTimeout(function () { $scope.$apply(function () {})})

Comment: That doenst work cause I have $timeout( function() {
   $scope.$apply(function () {
    alert("loaded");
    groupName = document.getElementById("permissionGroupName");
    console.log("groupName* * * ",$rootScope.groupId);
   });
  }, 1000);

And my console.log is always empty and I make a bad request to my api cause i dont have the value of groupName understand?